# sublime text3のファイル検索結果が<binary>となる件について

Tags: sublimetext

sublime text3ですが、テキストファイルを開いてファイル検索を行うと検索結果が<binary>と表示されます。
具体的には下記表示となります。

```
<binary>

384 matches in 1 file
```

マッチした行を表示させたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

**2017/01/26 13:42追記**
ファイル形式は.logで、linux上でscriptを使用して取得したテキストファイルとなります。
ちなみにctrl+fでの検索は問題なくできます。

Comment: 検索対象のファイルがバイナリとして認識されているのではないでしょうか。検索しようとしているファイルの具体的な情報を追記されると回答できるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflowに[同様](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030179/sublime-text-find-in-files-gives-binary-in-the-find-results)の質問がありました。

これによると以下のいずれかが原因となるようです。

1. ファイルサイズが大きすぎるための回避としてバイナリファイルとして検索されている
2. ファイル内に不正な文字があるため、バイナリファイルとして検索されている

一度ファイルを分割されて検索されてみてはいかがでしょうか。
ファイル分割後に検索し、どの分割されたファイルでも検索できれば1.が原因。
特定の分割されたファイルが検索できなければ2.が原因となると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。頂いた内容を元に確認したところ、ESCが入っていたのが原因でした。削除したところ問題なく検索できました。ありがとうございました。